# Multsite Child site Auto Content

Tags: multisite

I am creating a multi website for an organization and I want to do is reduce the step upon account activation so when the user register for a sub site.

When they select a custom theme, a default content, default plugin, default menu will automatically be configured or in other words, sample content and settings will automatically be configured on the selected theme
Similar to importing an XML, only want it upon user signup on multisite

Answer (score 0):

I use the premium plugin [New Blogs Template](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/new-blog-template) from WPMUDev.org.  I've been prepared to supplement it with custom code, but its been working good-enough so far.  It will copy menus, settings, and some content.  From your description, I think the plugin does everything you need.  It is designed to also be used in conjunction with the premium Gravity Forms plugin and it's registration add-on.

Comment: Thanks but that plugin only does upon registration, you will also need to integrate that with Prosite which is limited. what I would like to happen is even when switching theme once the child theme is activated, a premade content will still be rendered

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer, but maybe it will get you started.

I think I would hook into something like this...

```
add_action('switch_theme', 'mytheme_setup_options');

function mytheme_setup_options () {
  // todo: delete old sample data
  // todo: import new sample data
  // todo: figure it if this fires upon 1st activation, or just upon switches.
}
```

You could maybe use something like 'WordPress Importer' to facilitate the import, maybe even showing a pop-up explaining how to download and import the sample file.  I bought a premium theme that followed this approach, and it worked pretty well.

You'll have a challenge separating out your sample data, from any customization the user has already done, especially when they are switching back and forth between themes.  I suspect you don't want to overwrite their progress, nor pollute their site.  And you'll need to avoid duplicating entries if they keep switching back and forth.

Depending upon your situation, it might be smarter to have some sample sites, and show a admin message linking to the corresponding sample site.

Just some thoughts - good luck.

Comment: yes that logic are absolutely correct. I want to look at that theme if it does what I need, can you please share me the theme name. thanks

Comment: @jpl - "the theme name" - ouch, if I understand you correctly, you won't simply find a theme that does this.  If you go down this path, it's a bunch of custom code plus maybe a few helper plugins.  That being said, I wouldn't give up on first finding a good combo of plugins, but I think you'd be asking a lot.  Good luck.

Comment: okay i thought you bought a theme that exactly does what I was looking for